# How to add space or memory when reallocating

Tags: c

in this code that's NOT commented out i want to add to memory i think. This is about to be worded so very bad. basically, i want to be able to add elements to the list but i don't know exactly how. how to i increase the space which i'm reallocing do i do something like (something = realloc(blockhead_point, capacity++);) or am i thinking about this wrong?

```
struct blockhead_node{
    int x, y;
    int dx, dy;
    size_t capacity;
    int *data// account 4 mx and my
};


  void add_blockhead_for_mouse(struct blockhead_node * blockhead_list, int v, double mx, double my) // double pointer because we can't modify the lost it self
    {


    int blockhead_pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct blockhead_node) * capacity));
    realloc(blockhead_pointer, capacity);


    /*for (int c = 0; c >= blockhead_list; c++)
    {
        reallc(blockhead_list->size[0] + 1) = blockhead_list->data; //adding memory
        blockhead_list[0][-1] = mx; //add a bkhd to the end of the list

    }
    for (int q = 0; q >= blockhead_list; q++)
    {
        reallc(blockhead_list->size[1] + 1 = blockhead_list->data; //adding memory
        blockhead_list->size[1][-1] = my; //add a blockhead to the end of the list

    }*/
```

Comment: Did you meant `blockhead_list = malloc(sizeof(struct blockhead_node) * capacity)` ??, and if so, where is capacity defined? it is initialized?, if not, I have the same question for `blockhead_pointer`and blockhead_point.

Comment: I'll update the question give me a sec

Comment: Please get your identifiers correct. This is nonsense.(And:check your sizes ...)

Comment: are trying to create a new list each time or you wanna add to the existing list? because realloc is redundant after a malloc. if you are gonna extend existing list, then you should only realloc without malloc.

Comment: what's wrong with my identifier

Comment: it's hard to see what i'm exactly doing because the code is long and it wouldn't let me post most of it. i believe so i'm trying to create a "new list" i'm trying to extend the old one.

Comment: bloblockhead_point !=blockhead_pointer,  for a start.

Comment: ah, i see it sorry. i haven't been able to find my glasses. thanks

Comment: you're passing a void pointer to a pointer to int, which is perfectly legal, but in your case this is obviously a mistake, since you're allocating memory for several items of type `struct blockhead_node`, please find your glasses ASAP. ;)

Comment: I've been looking for months but thanks i fixed it